Is the hypothetical '(Don) Page curve' of evaporating black holes equal in time, so to speak, on both sides of the curve?
I have heard that Hawking radiation is slow at first, but rapidly increases when the black hole becomes much smaller... (I forget the formula...)
Does that mean that the second half of Page's curve, whereby the radiation contains 'information' that can be retrieved, takes place over a much shorter period of time than the unintelligible first half?

relevant lecture ntoes https://www.suvratraju.net/openscholar/suvrat/files/qabh_lec_19.pdf

Information in Black Hole Radiation, by Don N. Page (1993).
